# Is there a way to make export_graphviz fill nodes of classification trees as if it were a regression tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I'm working with binary classification on a very imbalanced dataset and when I export my decision tree to graphviz using [export_graphviz](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) and setting `filled` to `True` all the nodes of tree are filled with the same color. Is there a way to make the color vary with higher probabilities of belonging to the alternative class?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Modify dot output

Would it be a possibility to (maybe automatically) modify the dot output? Once you can identify the nodes in question, you could add (or adapt) the fillcolor attribute for those nodes.

## Option 2: configuration in sklearn

I do not know details about sklearn. But from the page you linked, many settings sound interesting, especially these:

- impurity
- label
- class_names